# Find maximum in list of objects in Python

Tags: python, list, object

I have a list of objects. Could someone help return the object with the highest score? For example:

```
objs = [
  {
    "name": "John",
    "score": 30
  },  
  {
    "name": "Josh",
    "score": 40
  },  
  {
    "name": "Jason",
    "score": 50
  },  
]
```

I need a method that will return the object with the highest score. In this case it should return

```
  {
    "name": "Jason",
    "score": 50
  }
```

So far I tried:

`print max(objs, key=attrgetter('score'))`

but it gives me `AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'score'`

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What problems did you run into when you tried to implement this yourself?

Comment: i just updated my question w/ the results of my attempts @pvg

Comment: Those aren't objects, they're dictionaries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Pandas

You can convert the dictionary to a `dataframe`, find the index of the max `score`, extract the entry and convert that back to a dictionary.

This is probably faster when you have a large number of objects.

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(objs)
df.iloc[df['score'].idxmax(),:].to_dict()
```

---

**Demo:**

```
import pandas as pd
```

Reading to a dataframe

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(objs)

print(df)
    name  score
0   John     30
1   Josh     40
2  Jason     50
```

Locating the index of the maximum `score`

```
df.iloc[df['score'].idxmax(),:]

name     Jason
score       50
Name: 2, dtype: object
```

Extracting the max and writing to a dictionary

```
max_obj = df.iloc[df['score'].idxmax(),:].to_dict()
print(max_obj)
{'score': 50, 'name': 'Jason'}
```

Comment: Pandas is great, but you can use python's built-in max function with a key lambda function.  It's much simpler.  More pythonic.  If you need to do this task, Pandas is a bit of overkill. See @ChipJust solution below.

Answer (score 4):

`operator.attrgetter()` is for attributes, e.g. `foo.bar`.

For item access you want `operator.itemgetter()` instead.

Comment: Do many people actually use the `operator` module like this? I usually just see a `lambda`.

Answer (score 2):

max(objs, key=lambda x: x['score'])

[The key argument specifies a one-argument ordering function like that used for list.sort().](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#max)

The most compact way to provide the function is [with lambda](http://www.secnetix.de/olli/Python/lambda_functions.hawk).

```
>>> max(objs, key=lambda x: x['score'])
{'name': 'Jason', 'score': 50}
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do the job as well,

`[a for a in objs if a["score"] == max([a["score"] for a in objs])]`

Returns,

`[{'score': 50, 'name': 'Jason'}]`

Comment: Keep in mind that this method is very inefficient and it's almost not worth it.

Answer (score 0):

Not a Python expert and I guarantee there is a simpler and less verbose way to complete.

Though, it works for me:

```
for x in objs:
    hiscore = 0
    count = 0
    if x.get('score') > hiscore:
        hiscore = x.get('score')
        count += 1
print("Highest score is {data[score]} from player {data[name]}".format(data=x))
```